# Admin can’t create order/reorder magento 2.4.5

Tags: admin, adminhtml, sales-order, magento2.4.5

Magento 2.4.5 issue where an Admin user can’t create orders nor reorders for customers.

> report.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in /app/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Block/Form.php:174

Answer (score 0):

[Admin can’t create order/reorder when Braintree payment enabled](https://href=%22/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/assets/BUNDLE-3137-composer.patch.zip?lang=en%22%3EBUNDLE-3137-composer.patch.zip%3C)

> Cause

```
   Incorrect class dependencies (vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Block/Form.php)
```

> Solution

Apply the patch provided in this article.

> Patch

```
The patch is attached to this article. To download it, click the following link:
```

[BUNDLE-3137-composer.patch.zip](https://href=%22/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/assets/BUNDLE-3137-composer.patch.zip?lang=en%22%3EBUNDLE-3137-composer.patch.zip%3C)

> vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Block/Form.php

```
 public function __construct(
     GatewayConfig $gatewayConfig,
     CcType $ccType,
     LoggerInterface $logger,
    + Data $paymentDataHelper,
     array $data = []
 ) {
     parent::__construct($context, $paymentConfig, $data);
     public function __construct(
        $this->gatewayConfig = $gatewayConfig;
        $this->ccType = $ccType;
        $this->logger = $logger;
       + $this->paymentDataHelper = $paymentDataHelper;
    }
```